# Understanding concepts with concurrent futures to speed up webscraping

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping, concurrency, concurrent.futures

I have a webscraping program that scrapes thousands of websites. However, it is very slow. I've found some things on concurrent.futures that I'm trying to implement; however, I can't seem to get a good grasp on how this works. I've attached a simple code below for someone to help explain the concept, but in my other program, it is iterating through x values, but it seems to be skipping some x's. I don't know if this is because multiple threads are running and it is missing them, or what is happening. I'm hoping an explanation of this code will help me figure out how to approach the other code.

When I run the code below, it prints out a bunch of numbers, and multiple times. For example, it shows 456, 789100, 123, 45, 678910012 all on separate lines, plus a bunch more. I'm not sure I understand why it is looping through multiple times and printing them all multiple times. Any help with these seemingly simple concepts would be much appreciated.

```
import time

import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed

a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
def printNumbers(a):
    print(a)


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:

    start = time.time()
    futures = [executor.map(printNumbers, a) for url in a]
    #results = []
    #for result in as_completed(futures):
    #    results.append(result)
    #    print(results)

    #futures = [executor.submit(testing,url) for url in urlList]
    #results = []
    #for result in as_completed(futures):
    #    results.append(result)
    end=time.time()
    print("Time taken: {:.6f}s".format(end-start))

print('break')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your code to make it work, the following will work:

```
import time
import concurrent.futures

a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]


def printNumbers(a):
    print(f'entered {a}')
    time.sleep(1)
    return a * a


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=30) as executor:
    for number, a_i in zip(a, executor.map(printNumbers, a)):
        print(number, a_i)
```

Output:

```
entered 0
entered 1
entered 2
entered 3entered 4

entered 5entered 6

entered 7
entered 8
entered 9
entered 10
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
10 100
```

Comment: Can you explain the concepts a little bit - for example, your code appears to loop through once. Why is mine looping through multiple times? How or what part of the code is preventing what you've done from that? In my actual code, it's scraping thousands of websites, so I'm trying to speed it up, but make sure each iterable is ran and ran only once.